# How to configure add-apt-repository to automatically update the packages index on debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt

On Ubuntu, the command `add-apt-repository` automatically update the package index after adding a repository but this feature isn't integrated in debian Buster.

How to configure `add-apt-repository` to automatically update the package index on debian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the version available in Debian 10, the `-u` option will update the package cache:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -u ...
```

(This isn’t documented in the man page.)

You can change the default by editing `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository`: change the default in

```python
    parser.add_option("-u", "--update", action="store_true",
        dest="update", default=False,
        help=_("Update package cache after adding"))
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the underlying philosophy behind the difference is that it's possible that you're in a position where you need to add multiple repositories one after the other and there's a good argument for wanting to defer the update until you've added them all.

Comment: @Shadur I think it’s more about Ubuntu having a newer version of `software-properties` ;-). I suspect the default was changed to make the tool easier to use — `add-apt-repository`, done, the new packages are available. The current version of `add-apt-repository` has an `-n` option to disable updating, for scenarios such as the one you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/627464/153195), I have copied `add-apt-repository` from Ubuntu bionic to my debian stable:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/software-properties-common_0.96.24.32.14_all.deb
ar x software-properties-common_0.96.24.32.14_all.deb
tar xvf data.tar.xz
```

To display the difference between the two files (validate the accepted answer)

```
diff usr/bin/add-apt-repository /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
```

Replacing the existing file:

```
sudo mv usr/bin/add-apt-repository /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
```